# the mean of "one's bearing" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the mean of "one's bearing" in the sentence "To be a conqueror in appearance, in one's bearing, is the first step toward success."? I referred to  dictionary and searched but I didn't understand the meaning in this sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: "The manner in which one carries or conducts oneself" (TFD)

Comment: @Kris Thanks for comment :-) but why you voted to close my question ? I searched and I wanted to use the knowledge of someone with more experience. By the way, I appreciate if you have any point and/or if I made a mistake.

Comment: Here on ELU, one who wants to ask a question is expected first look up a good dictionary and other online & offline references **and** mention what was found and why it was not satisfactory in the question, so that the answerers know your background effort and will be encouraged to help you if needed. *Bearing* is already well defined in all major dictionaries and therefore is considered General Reference on this site. As for meaning in context, it is quite obvious to a native speaker in this sentence. If you are not a native English speaker, you can ask on [ell.se] <-- please visit this site.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for help. What can I do now? I can't delete the question? English Language Learners is good idea...

Comment: "What can I do now?" -- Keep coming back. ELL & ELU can help you gain better understanding of the language and hopefully will prove useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One's bearing" is the impression your body language gives. If you walk in like a queen might, proud and regal, you could be said to have "The bearing of a queen."

Comment: See other (more relevant) definitions as well.

Comment: A markdown with no explanation changes nothing.